# How to fill in values in struct using a function?

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I want to call a function to fill in the values of a struct in C. I have the following code but I get errors like `[Error] request for member 'id' in something not a structure or union`.

```
#include <stdio.h> 

typedef struct {
    int       id;
    float    grades[3];
} student_t;

void scan_student (student_t *s) {
    printf("Please give student's info:\n");
    scanf("%d%f%f%f", s.id, s.grades[0], s.grades[1], s.grades[2]);
}

int main () 
{ 
    student_t stu2;

    scan_student(&stu2);

    printf("Student's info are:\n");
    printf("%6d %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f\n", stu2.id, stu2.grades[0], stu2.grades[1], stu2.grades[2]);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: try this -  &s.id

Comment: And... you should have tons of warnings here. The rule says: **warnings are not to be ignored** (at least unless you understand why the warning and why you can ignore it in that special use case)

Comment: @OldProgrammer - OP hasn't even got to that error yet!

Comment: Another thing is... use English, at least English identifiers (if your audience really does not know "grade"). As you realize right here, this is a global world. In modern languages like C# I suppose you could even use Greek identifiers, and certainly Greek strings (this web application allows me to write *βαθμός*) -- don't do that. Stick to 7 bit ASCII, English and 80 character lines unless there is a compelling reason not to.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider Yes, you are absolutely right! I'm sorry. I fixed the text.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`s` is a pointer, not a struct. That means you can't use `.` on it.

Instead you have to write `(*s).id` (dereference, then access struct member) or `s->id` (same thing, but shorter).

Also, `scanf` `%d` takes a pointer, so that should be `&s->id`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I also post an  example without using pointers:

```
#include <stdio.h> 

typedef struct {
    int       id;
    float    grades[3];
} student_t;

student_t scan_student () {
    student_t s;
    printf("Please give patient's info:\n");
    scanf("%d%f%f%f", &s.id, &s.grades[0], &s.grades[1], &s.grades[2]);
    return s;
}

int main () 
{ 
    student_t stu2;

    stu2= scan_student();

    printf("Student's info are:\n");
    printf("%6d %5.2f %5.2f %5.2f\n", stu2.id, stu2.grades[0], stu2.grades[1], stu2.grades[2]);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Passing `stu2` to `scan_student` as an argument is pointless in your example.

Comment: @FiddlingBits Has a good point. You can as well return a local variable (note: by value! returning pointers to locals is, of course, wrong); no need to pass anything as a parameter to the function. The way it is now means the following: (1) Create a local copy of the parameter (note: this is why you could as well use a local variable right away); (2) fill that; (3) return a temporary copy of the local variable on the stack; (3) copy that temporary back into `stu2`, overwriting whatever uninitialized values were present there.

Comment: I realize that I have two third steps in my above comment ;-). Oh well.